# ambiguous overload of function template

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

This (contrived) code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int i) : i_(i) {}

private:
    int i_;
};

template<typename T>
Foo<T> bar(const T& /*x*/, const Foo<T>& /*foo*/)
{
    std::cout << "first bar()" << std::endl;
    return Foo<T>(1);
}

template<typename T>
Foo<T> bar(int /*x*/, const Foo<T>& /*foo*/)
{
    std::cout << "second bar()" << std::endl;
    return Foo<T>(42);
}

int main()
{
    Foo<bool> f1(0);
    Foo<bool> f2 = bar(true, f1); // first bar()
    Foo<bool> f3 = bar(10, f1); // second bar()
    (void)f2; // avoid warning for unused variable
    (void)f3; // avoid warning for unused variable
    return 0;
}
```

doesn't do much, but compiles fine with g++ 4.7.2:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra foo.cpp
```

and it produces the expected result:

```
$ ./a.out 
first bar()
second bar()
```

When I change the template type from `bool` to `int` in `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    Foo<int> f1(0);
    Foo<int> f2 = bar(true, f1); // first bar()
    Foo<int> f3 = bar(10, f1); // second bar()
    (void)f2; // avoid warning for unused variable
    (void)f3; // avoid warning for unused variable
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compilation error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra foo.cpp 
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:30:29: error: call of overloaded 'bar(int, Foo<int>&)' is ambiguous
foo.cpp:30:29: note: candidates are:
foo.cpp:13:8: note: Foo<T> bar(const T&, const Foo<T>&) [with T = int]
foo.cpp:20:8: note: Foo<T> bar(int, const Foo<T>&) [with T = int]
```

The problem is that both versions of `bar()` collide in this case, and the compiler can't decide which to choose.

How could this be solved?

Comment: Class Foo is a template class, but the parameter is hardset to int. Shouldn't it be T?

Comment: if first param should be the same type of T then specialize, otherwise your example is maybe a bit too simplified.

Comment: As both functions do different things, you could just rename one of them...

Comment: How could this be solved ? Depends on which one you would pick, and why.

Answer (score 1):

Tag dispatching:

```
struct selector {};

template<typename T>
Foo<T> bar(const T& /*x*/, const Foo<T>& /*foo*/, const selector&)
{
    std::cout << "first bar()" << std::endl;
    return Foo<T>(1);
}

// call it
bar(1, f1, selector{});
```

It's an example only, assuming more overloads, more sophistication is needed.

As Johan correctly pointed out, enable_if works only on template methods.

Comment: If `T` is `int`, that is just a specialization, no need of `enable_if`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use partial template specialization of struct, something like:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T1, typename T2> struct bar;

    template <typename T> struct bar<T, T>
    {
        Foo<T> operator()() const
        {
            std::cout << "first bar()" << std::endl;
            return Foo<T>(1);
        }
    };

    template <typename T> struct bar<int, T>
    {
        Foo<T> operator()() const
        {
            std::cout << "second bar()" << std::endl;
            return Foo<T>(42);
        }
    };

    template <> struct bar<int, int>
    {
        Foo<int> operator()() const
        {
            std::cout << "third bar()" << std::endl;
            return Foo<int>(42);
        }
    };

}


template<typename T1, typename T2>
Foo<T2> bar(const T1& /*x*/, const Foo<T2>& /*foo*/)
{
    return detail::bar<T1, T2>()();
}
```

And test it with:

```
int main()
{
    Foo<int> f1(0);
    Foo<int> f2 = bar<int>(true, f1); // first bar()
    Foo<int> f3 = bar(10, f1); // second bar()
    (void)f2; // avoid warning for unused variable
    (void)f3; // avoid warning for unused variable
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
    Foo<bool> f1(0);
    Foo<bool> f2 = bar(true, f1); // first bar()
    Foo<bool> f3 = bar(10, f1); // second bar()
    (void)f2; // avoid warning for unused variable
    (void)f3; // avoid warning for unused variable
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use parameters give choosing option, you can choose which bar you want to use and that can destroy ambiguity.I hope this can help.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int i) : i_(i) {}

private:
    int i_;
};

template<typename T>
Foo<T> bar(const T& /*x*/, const Foo<T>& /*foo*/,int pick=0)
{
    std::cout << "first bar()" << std::endl;
    return Foo<T>(1);
}

template<typename T>
Foo<T> bar(int /*x*/, const Foo<T>& /*foo*/,double pick=0)
{
    std::cout << "second bar()" << std::endl;
    return Foo<T>(42);
}

int main()
{
    Foo<bool> f1(0);
    Foo<int> f15(0);
    Foo<bool> f2 = bar(true, f1); // first bar()
    Foo<int> f3 = bar(10, f15,1); // first bar()
    Foo<int> f35 = bar(10, f15,1.0); // second bar()
    (void)f2; // avoid warning for unused variable
    (void)f3; // avoid warning for unused variable
    return 0;
}
```